# addition of two differential forms with different degrees

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Does it make sense to add two differential forms with different degrees like $dx+dx\bigwedge dy$? If yes, what's the arguments of it?

I ask this because in text book, the vector space, $\Omega^*(M)$, of $C^\infty$ differential forms on a manifold $M$ is defined as

$\Omega^*(M)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\Omega^k(M)$,

where $\Omega^k(M)$ is the vector space of k-forms. It means each element in $\Omega^*(M)$ is uniquely a sum $\sum_{k=0}^n \omega_k$, $\omega_k\in \Omega^k(M)$.

Comment: I mean, sure, in the direct sum of those vector spaces you can write that. That's what a direct sum of vector spaces is.

Comment: But does $dx+dx\bigwedge dy$ make sense in terms of differential form? Let $\alpha= dx+dx\bigwedge dy$, then which one is correct: $\alpha(X)$ or $\alpha(X,Y)$?

Comment: It is a formal sum of differential forms, or if you like a section of the bundle $\oplus \Lambda^k T^*M$. There's no reason to believe there's some inherently, innately defined way of pairing it against vectors. (There is a reasonable pairing of $\oplus \Lambda^k(TM)$ with $\oplus \Lambda^k(T^*M)$ - if you like, the pairing of a k-form with an m-vector is zero if $k \neq m$. But this is neither here nor there, and is unlikely to have the geometric content you're looking for.)

Comment: Ok. But is such expression like $dx + dx \bigwedge dy$ really used in any math branch, or should never be used?

Comment: Sometimes certain operators are most naturally defined on the entire $\Omega^*$ at once, or other direct sums of bundles; the signature operator is defined as a differential operator $\oplus \Lambda^{even} T^*M \to \oplus \Lambda^{odd} T^*M$. So it's not impossible that it's useful. But it's not really anything to be concerned about.

Comment: I have the exact same question. Do you have the answer now?

Comment: I'm pretty sure spinors can be represented by certain combinations of differential forms of varying degrees

Comment: These are sometimes called inhomogeneous differential forms. One can define a Clifford product on such elements and analyse its spinor representations, which leads to writing the Dirac equation (describing all massive spin-1/2 particles) in terms of differential forms.